# Why am I seeing ads on websites including Wikipedia?

Tags: popups, advertisements

I was reading about hash functions on Wikipedia when this ad popped up. I was appalled and flabbergasted and annoyed to find advertisements akin to this one dotting my article like sprinkles on a cupcake.

Annoying popups appear after you hover over them.

[image: Annoying ads on Wikipedia]

I now notice that these ads are appearing on any web page I visit including Superuser.

Why? How can I get rid of them?

---

By the way, these ads have the very gall to surface on Superuser, as seen here:
[image: Ads on superuser]

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed?  If so, one of them is doing this.

Comment: Wow, that was it. I had a malicious extension called "GameVance" installed. Thank you for bringing that up and solving the problem!

Comment: Great, I have added it as an answer if you want to accept or upvote it.  Or provide your own answer as you identified the extension and accept your own answer.

Comment: This is sort of obvious that "GameVance" was doing this considering there is a huge "GameVance" logo in nearly every pop-up in that screenshot.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This is usually caused by "malicious" extensions, and removing the extension will normally solve the problem.

Comment: Some other malicious extensions: bing toolbar, ask toolbar, any toolbar. :(

Comment: This. Don't just remove the extension, but do an anti-virus/anti-malware scan on your computer. Most of the time, if you have something like this, there is also something else hidden on your computer.

Comment: @Demolishun Bookmarks toolbar?  (Well, I suppose, if it has Facebook on it...)

Comment: I think this is called [Adware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adware).

Answer (score 19):

It looks like someone downloaded a "free game" that came with some scummy advertising stuff. Just uninstalling the plugin won't get rid of everything:

- [Here is Gamevance.com's official information](http://gamevance.com/deactivate.php) on deactivating and uninstalling their software.
- [Here are some suggestions](http://www.exterminate-it.com/malpedia/remove-gamevance)  from a secondary source, including files and folders and registry settings to remove.

Luckily, [from the sounds of it](http://www.xp-vista.com/spyware-removal/remove-gamevance-removal-instructions), they're pretty good about actually uninstalling when you uninstall.

Answer (score 3):

In case the official instructions don't work, or even if they do, you might want to run an adware removal tool such as [Ad-Aware](http://www.lavasoft.com/).  For every piece of malware that asserts its existence you are likely to have a dozen or so that do not.

Answer (score -6):

Can also be because that website was running short of money and decided to accept ads - Wikipedia in particular was running short of money, but I have no information on whether they decided to accept ads.

If so, an antivirus program or an antispyware program will probably NOT remove the ads.

I've found a program that claims to remove even those, but I haven't tried it:

http://simple-adblock.com/

Comment: If you look at the screenshots, it is clear that the ads stem from adware or a rogue extension.