# How do I stop ads in my browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, virus, malware, advertisements

My web browsers all keep getting completely infested with ads any time I run them. I primarily use Chrome, although I have IE installed as well, and that program also has the problem.

I ran Norton 360 and MalwareBytes, and they both removed many things, but my problem persists. In Chrome, I deleted all plugins except native clients, and all extensions, after which I reinstalled AdBlock Plus. I made sure I had no additional tool bars or anything like that. I checked all programs that I know of to make sure that I didn't have anything unnecessary installed.

I am running Windows 8.1

Comment: As I have not enough reputation to comment your question I need to give that advice as an answer. Could you pls try running "adwcleaner" (follow the instructions) and report back after a reboot? Pls also check which pages are set as default on the different browsers as those may also cause some troubles if the starting page opens a website which reinstalls all previous deleted adware / malware. Cheers

Comment: This, and similar questions are pretty common here, so a lot of good information has been assembled under this question: http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc.  As a first step, see if that provides you with a solution.

Comment: Thank you for getting back. I did make sure of my default browsers prior to posting this question. I just forgot to mention it. I just now tried adwcleaner, and it did not fix the problem

Comment: I browsed it. Thank you. I tried scanning Kaspersky internet security and it is still there. I have a back of if windows but id really rather not have to do that. Is there anything you could suggest in detail?

Comment: You don't describe the specific types of ads, but here are some links to check: http://superuser.com/questions/433613/how-to-disable-javascript-modal-popup-ads, http://superuser.com/questions/626577/adblock-plus-doesnt-block-google-ads-how-to-enable, http://superuser.com/questions/886917/block-contextual-ads-based-on-browser-activity-from-google, http://superuser.com/questions/376690/why-am-i-seeing-ads-on-websites-including-wikipedia, http://superuser.com/questions/831994/advertisement-suddenly-appearing-on-top-of-almost-every-page, http://superuser.com/questions/61877/blocking-hover-ads

Comment: Did you recently install a questionable program?

Comment: Please check the entries of your hosts file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts).
Look for entries (lines) without a "#" on the beginning and check if they are somewhat suspicious. If you want you can upload the file somewhere and i'll have a look at it.

Comment: @sobrino  I'll check the entries of my "hosts file," thanks for the suggestion. I would be happy to send you something that I see or am suspicious of. Where could I do this from?

Comment: @badge-be what would you define as a questionable program?

Comment: @sobrino everytime that Malwarebytes scans my computer it says that it has saved a log file of removed items from my computer. Would it help if I shared that log with you?

Answer (score 0):

Run adwcleaner then if that doesn't fix the problem, scan program files and program data (this folder is hidden) and delete files that you know shouldn't be there. If that doesnt work, then just reinstall chrome.

Comment: adwcleaner was ran. I'll browse those files now. And I don't think that reinstalling chrome is the real answer to this problem, because it's inside of IE as well.